# I'm having issues with images imported as module imports in a Vue.js Project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, import, es6-modules

Currently, I have a folder in a Vue project which contains all my default images that it has been used through the app. The folder path is **`web/images/defaults/<imageNames>.png`**. I'm able import the images on my component by importing them individually like so:

**`import ImageName from '../../../../../../web/images/defaults/ImageName.png'`**

However, I want to create a file & add the images path to `const` variables & being able to import the file in the component.

I have tried:

```
import imageName1 from 'imageName1.png';
import imageName2 from 'imageName2.png';

const DEFAULT_IMAGES = {
  imageName1:'imageName1',
  imageName2:'imageName2',
};

export default DEFAULT_IMAGES;
```

Then, I imported it in my component like so:

```
import DEFAULT_IMAGES from '../../assets/images';
```

And I tried to **`v-bind`** to the **`src`** attribute

```
<img :src="DEFAULT_IMAGES.imageName1" >
```

However, it's not working as soon as I imported. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

I didn't include the right path to get the images. Originally, I tried to access the images in the same folder like so:

```
import imageName1 from 'imageName1.png';
import imageName2 from 'imageName2.png';

const DEFAULT_IMAGES = {
  imageName1:'imageName1',
  imageName2:'imageName2',
};

export default DEFAULT_IMAGES;
```

However, I needed to add **`./`** before the image name like so:

```
import imageName1 from './imageName1.png';
import imageName2 from './imageName2.png';

const DEFAULT_IMAGES = {
  imageName1:'imageName1',
  imageName2:'imageName2',
};

export default DEFAULT_IMAGES;
```